# Magento 2 How to update a record in quote item option table

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, magento2.2.6, magento2.3.2

I have add a custom column in a **`quote_item_option`** table, Now I want to update a record based on a **`quote item id`** and I use bellow code :

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Option\CollectionFactory $optioncollection,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepo,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Option $itemoption

    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->_optioncollection = $optioncollection;
        $this->_quoteRepo = $quoteRepo;
        $this->_itemoption = $itemoption;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $quote = $this->checkoutSession->loadCustomerQuote();
            $result = $quote->getData();            
            $quoteData = $this->_quoteFactory->load($result['quote_id_1']);
            $items = $quoteData->getAllItems();
            $optioncollection = $this->_optioncollection->create();
            foreach ($items as $value) {
                $optioncollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->addItemFilter($value['item_id'])->getData();
                if(!empty($optioncollection)){
                    foreach ($optioncollection as $v) {
                         $itemoption = $this->_itemoption->load($v['option_id']);
                         $itemoption->setCustomracking(json_encode($this->getValue()));
                         $itemoption->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Load customer quote error'));
        }
    }

    public function getValue(){
        $this->session->start();
        return $this->session->getRackingData();
    }

    public function unSetValue(){
        $this->session->start();
        return $this->session->getRackingData();
    }
```

can any one help me with my code ?

where i am wrong ?

Comment: When are you updating this value?

Comment: using this checkout_cart_save_after

Answer (score 1):

i got my solution as below changes in my code :

```
    try {
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->loadCustomerQuote();
        $result = $quote->getData();            
        $quoteData = $this->_quoteFactory->load($result['quote_id_1']);
        $items = $quoteData->getAllItems();
        $optioncollection = $this->_optioncollection->create();
        foreach ($items as $value) {
            $optioncollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->addItemFilter($value['item_id'])->getData();
            if(!empty($optioncollection)){
                foreach ($optioncollection as $v) {
                     $itemoption = $this->_itemoption->load($v['option_id']);
                     $itemoption->setCustomracking(json_encode($this->getValue()));
                     $itemoption->save();
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __($e->getMessage().'Load customer quote error'));
    }
```